# PyCharm & console don't let me use local modules

Tags: python, import, module, package, pycharm

I'm absolutely frustraded about the fact that I can't start my Python journey. I have a simple service which I use as a training with Python which is new for me.
I've downloaded PyCharm and as long as I had one file, everything was fine.
That I decided to to some structure and suddenly my project stopped working.
I have a structure like:

```
project/
project/employees
project/employees/__init__.py
project/employees/employees.py
project/server.py
project/venv/
project/venv/(...)
```

The `project` is a source root.

And yet I have something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/server.py", line 5, in <module>
      from employees.employees import Employees, EmployeesName
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\employees\employees.py", line 4, in <module>
      from server import db_connect
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\server.py", line 5, in <module>
      from employees.employees import Employees, EmployeesName
ImportError: cannot import name 'Employees'
```

I tested this with VS Code and CMD and the same happend.
I would be grateful for any suggestions!

EDIT:
`employees.py`:

```
from flask_jsonpify import jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource

from server import db_connect


class Employees(Resource):
    (...)


class EmployeesName(Resource):
    (...)
```

Comment: What does `employees.py` look like?

Comment: @JordanBonitatis - post is edited. Classes are hidden because they don't matter here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you have a circular dependency.
In `employees.py` you import `server.py`; and vice versa.
You have to rearrange your `.py` files in order that not to happen anymore.